# PHP regular expression using groups to match words (preg_match)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match 2 words in a regular expression using preg_match.
This is a simplified version of my statement with the actual code below.
The expression doesn't work when I use 2 groups in the expression. Please help.

If preg_match(string or string) and (string or string) {
do this
}

```
$subject = 'over £200 and under £300';

$minPrice = 0;
$maxPrice = 10000;

if (preg_match_all( '#£.*?([0-9]+)#i', $subject, $priceMatches)) {
    foreach ($priceMatches as $price) {}
     if (preg_match('/(over|above)(under|below|beneath)/i',$subject)) {
        $minPrice = $price[0];
        $maxPrice = $price[1];
        $priceOrder = "#!No=0&Nf=P_Price|BTWN+".$minPrice."+".$maxPrice."&N=&side=&Ns=P-SYSTEM_Price_Revenue|1&perPage=12";
        echo 'MIN PRICE ' . $minPrice . "\n";
        echo 'MAX PRICE ' . $maxPrice . "\n";

    } else {
   echo "no e found";
    }
} else {
   echo "no e found";
}
```

?>

Comment: So, you're trying to pull the minimum and maximum price from some kind of description?

Answer (score 0):

If the order of what you are always matching will always be the same, you simply need to change your regular expression to:

```
/(over|above).*(under|below|beneath)/i
```

This will allow for anything between the two words. Previously, your regular expression was expecting the words to be back-to-back (which wasn't the case).